# Play! Framework templates on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, templates, playframework

As far as I learned there is no possibility to write directly to the filesystem on GAE.

Since the templates are stored in the app/view directory how do you solve the problem to have some interface that is used to editing the templates that are being used? Is it possible to have template editors who have access to the new version's template files, or they must work on a separate development server and when everyone is done then the app admin can upload the new version to GAE?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best solution is to store the templates directly in GAE? In the datastore itself or in the blobstore... I think nothing prevents Play! from extracting its VirtualFile from a datastore instead of the file system. But, you need to tweak a bit this part of Play! I don't think it's really terrible but it's not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can save them in blobstore so it will slow. You could make a hybrid solution using Memcache + Datastore or play around with the Files API